# RTP to Live Smooth Streaming

Tags: iis, video-streaming, rtp, live-streaming, smooth-streaming

I have a RTP video stream that I want to send to a set-top box. Unfortunately, the set-top box doesn't support RTP and I have convert it to Smooth Streaming.

I've tried using Wowza Media Server to do the stream conversion but it did not work; the generated manifest is different from how the STB expects it to be and the STB closes the connection.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found three ways of doing it:

1. Receive the RTP stream with a virtual camera DirectShow filter and use that camera in the Expression Encoder SDK to generate a Live Smooth Stream.
2. Build a DirectShow graph that receives the RTP stream and use it with the IIS Smooth Streaming Format API to create the Live Smooth Stream.
3. Play the RTP stream (using VLC, for instance) and use Expression Encoder to do a Live Smooth Stream of the screen capture. Pretty messy, but works in a pinch.